# Should I care about incrementing primary keys in a sql Database shown to the user

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Currently i am starting to create a database for an application with many relations.

Therefore, many ID's will be displayed to the user. Now I wonder how I should build the database structure (scheme).
And even if I overthink the topic, I still want a reliable solution that is at least somewhat "production" ready. Better to think too big than too small.

The real problem are the Primary Keys. At the very beginning I had shown those to the user. Then when I did some searching, I found out that this is generally not the best option. UUID's/GUID's were recommended. Thereupon I rebuilt the schema of the database. There was still the `integer pk`, but the column "uuid" was added. The user then always entered the uuid and this was then internally translated to the id/pk to work with.

But this was very complex when it came to introduce new classes and functions, because a lot of joins had to be used (also not very efficient). At that time (currently I use Laravel as PHP framework), I didn't know Laravel that well either - today probably only a bit more. So I didn´t used `Eloquent` and `:with()`

As I asked here, I found the multiple calls too complex and just not worth it:
[Is it a good practice to have two unique IDs for an SQL database?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/444150/is-it-a-good-practice-to-have-two-unique-ids-for-an-sql-database)

There and in some other parts of the internet it was recommended to use only one id. Others say you should never show a pk and others say you should do something like my second attempt.

I know there's no master answer to this, but I'm hoping to maybe reach someone who has a long experience.
Because really I'm just asking myself the question:
Is it really as bad to show the internal ID when it is well secured by validations? Because, at least for me, it´s very hard to build a working `externally <-> internally` translation without ending in a mess.

So if you suggests the option to use a "translator key" or something like this (so for example that "xadse81" points to the internal id "1") Could you please attach an example for Laravel for easy "translation"? (I want to do a lot with "::with()") and currently such a translation doesn't work at all.
Below are some excerpts from my databse scheme attached

`User`:

```
            $table->id('user_id');
            $table->efficientUuid('uuid')->index()->unique();
            $table->string('user_name', 64)->unique();
            $table->string('user_firstname', 128);
            $table->string('user_lastname', 64);
            $table->string('user_password', 128);
            $table->string('user_mail', 128)->unique();
            $table->string('user_phone', 20)->unique();
            $table->dateTime('user_birth_date');
            $table->boolean('user_verified')->default(false);
            $table->timestamp('user_created')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('user_updated')->useCurrent()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
```

```
    public function roles(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Role::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

`Role:`

```
            $table->id('role_id');
            $table->efficientUuid('uuid')->index()->unique();
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->bigInteger('region_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->tinyInteger('type');
            $table->timestamp('role_created')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('role_updated')->useCurrent()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
            $table->unique(['user_id', 'region_id']);
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('user')->
                onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('region_id')->references('region_id')->on('region')->
                onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

```
    public function user(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,);
    }

    public function region(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Region::class);
    }
```

`Region:`

```
            $table->id('region_id');
            $table->efficientUuid('uuid')->index()->unique();
            $table->string('region_name', 128)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('region_created')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('region_updated')->useCurrent();
```

At the end I hope I get results like this:

```
"user": {
        "uuid": "someTypeOfID",
        "user_name": "Name",
        "user_firstname": "Name1",
        "user_lastname": "Name2",
        "user_mail": "Mail",
        "user_phone": "Tel",
        "user_verified": 0,
        "roles": [
            {
                "role_id": someTypeOfID,
                "region_id": someTypeOfID,
                "type": 0
            }
        ]
    }
```

with calling somewhat like:
`User::with('roles')->where('id', 'ID')->first();`

Comment: use have generally bigint or uuids, they are the linking column to the subsequent tables are are **never** shown to the user, as he can with that information make much destruction. You will have a form where you only display the infomation that is usefull to the user, and never the foreignkeys for example. Why do we use uuids instead of bigint, a problem arises, when the user can enter data or new records with out connection to the sql server, we can't use bigint, as they could be double entries, so uuids are used, so that no collison can occur, but strings are slower than bigints

Comment: @nbk. Therefore I use uuid´s as binary(16).

Comment: that actually doesn't matter int are faster

Comment: It sounds like you are following some misguided advice about implementing _"security through obscurity"_. UUIDs are not a substitute for proper implementation of security controls within your application. Do not expect the obscurity of an identifier to provide any level of security!

Comment: btw, "hashids" are a way to not expose the primary keys in a meaningful way

Answer (score 0):

Using autoincrement as primary key and adding uuid as a column to be used in the url is the best approach, as this will keep the database table and index size small and more efficient even insert operation will be faster as the db knows exactly the page that new rows will be insterted to.

to get your final result you could use [laravel resources](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources) and change the response to the what ever you want and maybe change the id in your response to $this->uuid which will return the uuid as the id in all your responses and even further you can tell laravel to handle the [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-key) for you and use the uuid

you can make a UserResource using php artisan make:resource UserResource

in the UserResource add all the field you want to return, something like below

```
return [
'uuid' => $this->uuid,
// rest of yourfields,
'roles' => new RoleResourceCollection($this->roles)
];
```

and do the same in your RoleResource

and here is a link to a great article by Tobias Petry that explain the same approach your asking for https://sqlfordevs.com/uuid-prevent-enumeration-attack